# Python re sub: capture group in greedy way

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract digits in fallowing manner (bolded to be extracted)

0 -> **2** {2020-04-07 15:03}

0 -> 2 {2020-04-07 15:03} -> **67** {2020-04-07 15:20}

With below code:

```
a = '0 -> 2 {2020-04-07 15:03} -> 67 {2020-04-07 15:20}'
b = re.sub(r'^.*(\d+)\s({.+})$', r'\1', a)
print(b)
> 7
```

But I only get match on one (last) digit. Why greedeness is not working here?

Comment: Greedy matching is working with the `.*`. Change to `.*?` and then you’ll get 67.

Comment: There's no point to use `re.sub` to extract something from a string, use `re.search` instead. Use a word-boundary `\b` to be sure to start at the first digit of your target number. Also, rewritting your pattern in a more descriptive way will probably make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
re.sub(r'^.*\s(\d+)\s{.+}$', r'\1', a)
```

I added a `\s` before the capture number to make sure that it's preceded by a space.